# Flutter Screenshot Package From Widget Width Was Called On Null

Tags: flutter, image, dart, screenshot

I am working with the [Screenshot package](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot/example) to capture an image of a `LinearPercentIndicator` widget. However, I keep getting the error when the function is called

```
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'width' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: width
```

I am not sure where this error is coming from. Any suggestions? The function is below

```
  Future<String> progressBarPath(double progress) async {
    final progressFile = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/image.png');
    var indicator = LinearPercentIndicator(
      percent: progress > 1.0 ? 1.0 : progress,
      width: 100,
      lineHeight: 13,
      animation: true,
      animationDuration: 1000,
      progressColor: FlutterFlowTheme.primaryColor,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF1F4F8),
      center: Text(
        formatNumber(
            progress > 1.0 ? 1.0 : progress,
            formatType: FormatType.percent),
        style: FlutterFlowTheme.bodyText1.override(
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 12,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      barRadius: Radius.circular(20),
    );

//this is where the conversion to an image should occur
    screenshotController.captureFromWidget(
      InheritedTheme.captureAll(context, Material(child: indicator)),
          delay: Duration(seconds: 1),
    ).then((capturedProgress) async {
      await progressFile.create(recursive: true);
      await progressFile.writeAsBytes(capturedProgress);
    });
    print(progressFile.path);
    return progressFile.path;
  }
```